# Loop on list and dictionary

Tags: python, loops, ansible

I do not understand how to use `loop` for my script.

I would like to loop on my task `vswitch` (`VS_VMKERNEL`) and my host list (`hostname`) but I have systematically a syntax error.

I need loop on VS VMKERNEL because i vould like use this task for many different vswitch and host

The error is

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'str object' has no attribute 'name'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/root/dev-ansible/tasks/LAB-010-Vswitch.yml': line 1, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Adding Vswitch VMKERNEL\n ^ here\n"}

```yaml
#task######################################
- name: Adding Vswitch VMKERNEL
  vmware_vswitch:
    hostname: '{{ item.1 }}'
    username: '{{ useresxi }}'
    password: '{{ passesxi }}'
    switch: "{{ item.0.name }}"
    nics: "{{ item.0.uplink1|default(omit)}}"
    nics: "{{ item.0.uplink2|default(omit)}}"
    mtu: "{{ item.0.mtu }}"
    validate_certs: no
  delegate_to: localhost
  loop: "{{ VS_VMKERNEL|product(hostname)|list }}"
  #loop: "{{ VS_VMKERNEL|subelements('hostname') }}"
  #loop: "{{ VS_VMKERNEL|product(hostname)|list }}"
  #loop: "{{ VS_VMKERNEL|dictsort('hostname') }}"
```

```yaml
#vars################################################
# ESXI Infra
hostname:
  - '192.168.218.50'
  - '192.168.218.51'
useresxi: root
passesxi: "-------"
#vswitch base
VS_VMKERNEL:
  name: VS-VMKERNEL
  uplink2: vmnic5
  mtu: 1500
```

Comment: What is your script, please include it in the question, and also what is your error message ?

Answer (score 0):

Well since `VS_VMKERNEL` is a simple dictionary and not a list of dictionary nor a dictionary of list, you can use it as is, no need to use a combination between it and your `hostname` list.

This task should do:

```yaml
- name: Adding Vswitch VMKERNEL
  vmware_vswitch:
    hostname: '{{ item }}'
    username: '{{ useresxi }}'
    password: '{{ passesxi }}'
    switch: "{{ VS_VMKERNEL.name }}"
    nics: "{{ VS_VMKERNEL.uplink1 | default(omit) }}"
    nics: "{{ VS_VMKERNEL.uplink2 | default(omit) }}"
    mtu: "{{ VS_VMKERNEL.mtu }}"
    validate_certs: no
  delegate_to: localhost
  loop: "{{ hostname }}"
```

Comment: Thanks you really for your help. I haven't been clear im my question. I need loop on VS VMKERNEL because i vould like use this task for many different vswitch and host.

Answer (score 0):

I found with a "with_nested" that works! But with variables in list.

My actual solution

```
- name: Add a VMware vSwitch with multiple NICs
  community.vmware.vmware_vswitch:
    hostname: "{{ item[1]}}"
    username: "{{ esxi_username }}"
    password: "{{ esxi_password }}"
    switch: "{{ item[0].name }}"
    nics: "{{ item[0].nic1|default(omit)}}"
    nics: "{{ item[0].nic2|default(omit)}}"
    mtu: "{{ item[0].mtu }}"
    number_of_ports: 2
    validate_certs: no
  delegate_to: localhost
  loop: "{{vs|product(hostname)|list}}"
```